# I am not getting address of event in Eventbrite API search respose

Tags: eventbrite

I am using Eventbrite API to search events around me and to locate them on map,but I am unable to get the address information in search response.

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: after taking the credentials, I am hitting this url https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=London&token=MY_TOKEN which results a Json response and I am not able to get the event address in this response

Comment: update your question with code you have done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add one more param in your request like below:-

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Indore&expand=organizer,venue&token=MY_EVENTBRITE_TOKEN

Answer (score 2):

In your event search responses you should find a `"venue_id"` field.

You will then need to [make another call to the API](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/venues/#ebapi-get-venues-id) to get the venue details:

For example:
    https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/VENUE_ID/?token=YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN

Returns ..

`{
  "address":{
    "address_1":"101 foobar st",
    "address_2":null,
    "city":"Sydney",
    "region":"NSW",
    "postal_code":"2000",
    "country":"AU",
    "latitude":"-33.8737891",
    "longitude":"151.213161",
    "localized_address_display":"101 foobar st, Sydney, NSW 2000",
    "localized_area_display":"Sydney, NSW",
    "localized_multi_line_address_display":[
      "101 foobar st",
      "Sydney, NSW 2000"
    ]
  },
  "resource_uri":"https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/25210646/",
  "id":"25210646",
  "age_restriction":null,
  "capacity":null,
  "name":"Sydney",
  "latitude":"-33.8737891",
  "longitude":"151.213161"
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the request as per your way!

For Helpful: https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/quickstart/

By latitude,longitude,within:

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.latitude=23.06&location.longitude=72.53&location.within=100km&token= Your_personal_OAuth_token

Comment: look at link formatting here in SO! Links should be formatted in a shorter way if they are not useful to have them plain.